# Is there request scope in spring websockets ?(websocket scope == session scope)

Tags: java, websocket, scope, aspectj, spring-messaging

I know that spring has websocket scope.
But it means that it will collect values within session.

I need to have something like request scope. It shoud start when we receive values in controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/common/url")
public void foo(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor, StubObject payLoad) {
   Foo foo = someService.toDoSmth();
   simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, "path/to/queue", foo );
```

and when last line will be finished it should disappear.

Why do I need this?

I use aspects in my code.
When I receive message I should create entry in database
When I invoke `someService` I need update entry which I created in previous step
When I send message through  `simpMessagingTemplate` I need update entry one more time.